# Using udpsink to stream h264 with gstreamer ( c++ )

Tags: udp, streaming, h.264, gstreamer

I'm trying to stream h264 video over the network using gstreamer ( in windows ) over UDP.
First if I use a pipeline like this, everything appears to be ok, and I see the test pattern:

videotestsrc, ffmpegcolorspace, x264enc, rtph264pay, rtph264depay, ffdec_h264, ffmpegcolorspace, autovideosink

Now I decided to divide this pipeline in client and server parts, transmitting the stream over udp using udpsink and udpsrc.

```
Server: videotestsrc, ffmpegcolorspace, x264enc, rtph264pay, udpsink
Client: udpsrc, rtph264depay, ffdec_h264, ffmpegcolorspace, autovideosink
```

On server I use something like that:

```
source = gst_element_factory_make ("videotestsrc", "source");
ffmpegcolortoYUV = gst_element_factory_make ("ffmpegcolorspace", "ffmpegcolortoYUV");
encoder = gst_element_factory_make ("x264enc", "encoder");
rtppay = gst_element_factory_make ("rtph264pay", "rtppay");
udpsink = gst_element_factory_make ("udpsink", "sink");

g_object_set (source, "pattern", 0, NULL);
g_object_set( udpsink, "host", "127.0.0.1", NULL );
g_object_set( udpsink, "port", 5555, NULL );
```

Then I add the elements to the pipeline and run, there are no errors anywhere.
Now if I look for UDP port 5555, it's not listening!!!!

The client part also runs but if there is no UDP port listening on server side it won't work.

EDIT: In fact I was very close to the solution... If I start the client it works, but with some problems on the visualization... I think the problem is the x264enc configuration. Anybody knows how to change x264enc parameters like speed-preset or tune???
I tried to instantiate GstX264EncPreset or GstX264EncTune but I have no the declarations of these strcutures.
Anybody knows any way to setup x264enc in other way, like parsing a string or something like that?

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an older post, but you can set the GstX264EncPreset value using a simple integer that corresponds to the preset value.

`g_object_set(encoder, "speed-preset", 2, NULL);` works for me. The values can be found using `gst-inspect-1.0 x264enc` and are as follows:

```
  speed-preset        : Preset name for speed/quality tradeoff options (can affect decode compatibility - impose restrictions separately for your target decoder)
                        flags: readable, writable
                        Enum "GstX264EncPreset" Default: 6, "medium"
                           (0): None             - No preset
                           (1): ultrafast        - ultrafast
                           (2): superfast        - superfast
                           (3): veryfast         - veryfast
                           (4): faster           - faster
                           (5): fast             - fast
                           (6): medium           - medium
                           (7): slow             - slow
                           (8): slower           - slower
                           (9): veryslow         - veryslow
                           (10): placebo          - placebo
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the caps on the udpsrc element to "application/x-rtp".